# Asp classico com Asp .net

Tags: aplicação-web, asp

Tenho um projeto Asp net e gostaria de aproveitar uma pagina de outro projeto, porem ele é asp classico, fiz algumas pesquisas e vi que dava pra fazer essa "mesclagem", mas ninguem disse ao certo como fazer. Alguem poderia ajudar?
A unica solução que disseram foi rodar o projeto no iis e  configura-lo, porem só consegui configurar para rodar separadamente, o projeto com a pagina asp classica não roda suas funções.

Comment: o mais recomendável seria a migração das telas, conforme é dito neste link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782025/can-i-combine-asp-net-4-0-with-classic-asp-or-can-i-convert-classic-asp-to-asp

Comment: Não resolveu meu problema, eu quero só rodar uma pagina dentro do meu projeto, ir de uma pagina aspx para asp. Acabei de ver que aspx e asp não compartilham a mesma session.

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de as duas linguagens de programação terem a mesma nomenclatura:

ASP **(extensão: asp)**

ASP.NET (extensão: aspx)

São linguagens totalmente diferentes em sessions e métodos, para tentar sanar este problema tente tercerizar a ponte entre uma linguagem e outra.
Quando quero compartilhar dados de uma página *.asp para outra *.php, faço a primeira página gerar um arquivo ***XML*** o qual qualquer outra linguagem de programação pode recuperar os dados e tratar e/ou exibir.

Comment: Sim, acabei achando a solução, mas realmente o problema é as sessões que não passam de uma para a outra, sua resposta consta com a qual encontrei então muito obrigado Wilson Rosa Gomes